# Does ggplot2 always require that variables be named?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to use ggplot without first assigning names to the variables in the data.frame?  My intended use is early exploration of large datasets, the kind that involves trying one form of a question or possibility then moving on to the next.  I record short comments about what is being explored but seldom name the rows and columns of the one-time-use variables I derive.

To see the data, I make quick and dirty plots:

```
plot(matrix.name)
```

or more often

```
plot(x = array.name[1, , 1], y=array.name[ , , 1])
```

At times I’d like to use ggplot2’s features instead.  The requisite as.data.frame(matrix.name) conversion is quick, but then is there a way to pass the necessary arguments to `aes()` without assigning row and column names?  As best I have been able to research, `aes` requires variable names.

Thank you very much for your help.  I will repeatedly have occasion to use any answers.

Comment: `ggplot` only accepts data.frames for its `data` parameter, and so any variables have names. You can reference them by string instead of bare name with `aes_string` if you like, and thus you can just index the names (e.g. `aes_string(x = names(as.data.frame(mat))[1])`), but it's usually easier and more useful to just use the variable names directly.

Comment: The help pages for R functions are generally very specific. Hadley is a smart enough R programmer to (usually) document the requirements carefully. If he says the argument needs to be a dataframe then you _should_ believe him. If you wnat to make a helper functions coerces an array argument to dataframe which will name the columns if they aren't there or allow renaming them is they are, you could then use the new columnames.

Comment: @alistaire - Sorry, newbie struggling to figure out how to post a comment and hit enter before I finished.  In a run-on paragraph, unfortunately:  What I tried with your suggestion in order to make a 2-D plot but that did not work is    test.me <- as.data.frame(mat)    rownames(test.me) <- paste0("row", rownames(test.me))   [This part was because I figured r didn't want numbers as names] ggplot(test.me, aes_string(
   x = names(test.me),
   y = rownames(test.me)))
 + geom_point()     I'll keep looking at instructions so I can format this better.  Thank you.

Comment: A concrete example: `mat <- matrix(rnorm(20), 10); df <- as.data.frame(mat); ggplot(df, aes_string(x = names(df)[1], y = names(df)[2])) + geom_point()` But it's a lot easier to read `ggplot(df, aes(x = V1, y = V2)) + geom_point()`, though you need to look at the data.frame first to see the names. Note that row names are useless here; make them a column of the data.frame if they contain relevant data.

Comment: @alistaire - Thank you for your patience.  I wasn't clear that what I want to make is a scatterplot.  So I need many(!) columns and rows. That's why I remain interested in how to get the second dimension / y-axis in there.  I'll keep working on it.